# Select multiple similar rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with c 1m rows. Let's say they might look like this:

```
name  
flower 1  
flower 2  
flower 3  
fish 1975  
ocean  
field  
tree 1  
tree 2  
tree 3
```

I need to flag the sequences.

Currently, I'm using something like regexp `'([a-zA-Z] [0-9]+)$'`, works ok but picks up `'fish 1975'` which ideally I want to avoid because it only appears once and thus is probably not a sequenced entry, it just has a number at the end.

I can't figure out how / if I can say "Get me rows that end in a number as long as there are N other rows that have the same characters before the number" in one step in mysql.

Comment: Please post a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Consider doing this in the appplication layer, in general this is not something where MySQL is good in but sure its possible... But which MySQL version do you have as MySQL 8 most likely makes it alot more easy.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query:

```
select 
  left(name, char_length(name) - locate(' ', reverse(name))) prefix,
  count(*) counter                                                             
from tablename 
where name regexp '([a-zA-Z] [0-9]+)$'
group by prefix
```

you get all the names without the numbers at the end and the number of times they occur in the column `name`.
Join it to the table and apply the condition you need in the WHERE clause:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select 
    left(name, char_length(name) - locate(' ', reverse(name))) prefix,
    count(*) counter                                                             
  from tablename 
  where name regexp '([a-zA-Z] [0-9]+)$'
  group by prefix
)g on t.name like concat('%', g.prefix, ' %')
where g.counter > 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tiJJVNTYyv35QiyjwMi3X/2).
Results:

```
| name     |
| -------- |
| flower 1 |
| flower 2 |
| flower 3 |
| tree 1   |
| tree 2   |
| tree 3   |
```

Comment: That's a beautiful thing, thank you.